# Android App: Handling links opened elsewhere in Android with 'Open With...'

Tags: android, webview, hyperlink

I'm very new to Android app development, but I have a website which has an app - the app simply uses webview to load the site. Very simple so far.

Because desktop users will be using the site itself, and they'll want to share links they encounter on the website, mobile users might, say, go on Facebook, see a link they want to visit and it would simply open the website in the browser, rather than loading that URL in the app, which obviously fragments/confuses users (the website has a log in system, for starters, and they'd need to log in again from the android browser).

Is there any way of listening out for links to the website within Android and opening these with the app's webview, rather than in the browser? I know Facebook has fb:// links which open the app instead.

The problem's further complicated, though. Effectively, to prevent internal links launching an external android browser, I have a filter to the effect of:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
     if (url.contains("root_address_of_site/page/")) {

         return false;
     } else {
         view.getContext().startActivity(
                  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
     }
        return true;

 }
```

Within the app, you can share a link to Facebook, Twitter and Calendar via basic urls, so the link to Twitter might be https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=root_address_of_site/page/&text=page_name&tw_p=tweetbutton&url=root_address_of_site/page/. Of course, this would simply be snagged by the filter because the intent URL 'contains' 'root_address_of_site/page/'. I wonder if there's a way to change the filter so that it's 'begins with', rather than 'url.contains'? That would mean twitter/facebook links would still open externally, but links to the site itself would still open within the app, no matter what.

I hope that makes sense - it's tough to describe. Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 0):

Here is [documentation about how to handle your own links in app](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html)

So you need to register one of your activities as handler for needed uri pattern:

```
<activity android:name="OpenCustomUriActivity">
     <intent-filter>
          <data
              android:scheme="http"
              android:host="yoursite.com"
              android:pathPrefix="pathOnYourSiteIfNeeded"
              />
      </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then just handle intent in activity and do what you need.